# How to change Twitter profile text color?

Tags: twitter, profile

How can one change the text color for one's profile such as in the popup in Twitter?

The text being displayed includes a few items like name and web site link.

Comment: Viewing a profile in your stream, or setting yours to show when others access it from a tweet or stream? (Not when they're on your profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your profile's text color by changing the theme. To do so:

- Click on your avatar image in the upper right corner of the screen
- On the dropdown menu, click **Profile**
- Click the **Edit profile** button (on the right side of the screen)
- Click the **Theme color** button*
- Select a preset color, or choose your own by typing in the value in the input box** and clicking on the check mark
- Click the **Save changes** button (on the right side)

* Depending on your current theme, this button may be hard to spot because of its color. It is sandwiched between the **Website** and **Birthday** input boxes on the left side.

** If you don't see an input box, click the plus sign (`+`) after the colors to make it appear.

*These instructions are assuming you're using Twitter in a web browser. Changing the text color from another Twitter client will be done differently.*